# Translations in sourceLanguage does not work in Yii2 application

Tags: translation, yii2

I'm using a translations based on keywords in my Yii2 application (I know, that this isn't best option, but I don't have other). I've prepared `@app/messages/pl/app.php` and `@app/messages/en/app.php` files with translation strings using keywords, instead of full-featured sentences or words:

```
<?php
    return [
        'name_english'=>'Name in English',
        'keywords_english'=>'Keywords in English'
    ];
?>
```

I have set my application to use *Polish* language as default:

```
'language' => 'pl',
'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
```

And I'm invoking translation:

```
Yii::t('app', 'keywords_english');
```

Everything works fine, when language is actually set to base, *Polish* (`pl`):

[image]

But, when I change it to *English* (`en`; either by setting `Yii::$app->language` during runtime or by changing application configuration), translation is not performed and I'm getting `keywords_english`:

[image]

I have put `die()` in the beginning of `@app/messages/pl/app.php` and `@app/messages/en/app.php` files and I can clearly see, that when language is set to *English*, second file is not being included by Yii2 (application run follows), while, when language is *Polish*, first file is included and application flow breaks on that `die()`.

What am I missing? Why Yii2 is not using translations from `@app/messages/en/app.php` file, if language is set to *English* (`en`)?

**EDIT**: By default, I was not altering default `i18n` component configuration in my application's configuration as I found no need for that. Translation files are stored in default position (`@app/messages/<language>/`) and are using default class (`yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource`). And this is working for all languages except `sourceLanguage`. At some point, I tried to alter configuration:

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        '*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
            'basePath' => '@app/messages'
        ],
    ],
],
```

But, it brought no change (why should it -- it still uses default settings).

Comment: Show  `i18n` from config

Comment: See updated question. I'm not configuring `i18n` in any way. Why should I? I want to use default settings and this should work for `en`, if it works for `pl`, right?

Comment: Try that: `'translations' => [
                'app*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'app' => 'app.php',
                    ],
                ],`

Comment: This works fine! Even without `fileMap` part. `'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US'` is the key. Make it an answer, so I can accept it. However, this brings even more questions: Why do I have to set `'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US'`, when I don't use two-part language codes and my application's source language is `en`, not `en_US` (with `en` your solution does not work)? Why this work for `app` or `app*`, but not for `*` (translate all categories)? Etc. Implementation of this in Yii2 is really strange for the beginners.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [*samdark* at Yii Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63015-translations-in-sourcelanguage-does-not-work-in-yii2-application/page__view__findpost__p__278186), this is by design. Translations are not performed, if `language` = `sourceLangage`.

To workaround this, and force translations in this case, one must set [`forceTranslation`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-messagesource.html#$forceTranslation-detail) to `true`.

Therefore, one must add / modify `i18n` component in `components` section of application's config in the way similar to this:

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'app' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'forceTranslation' => true
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                ],
            ],
```

Answers for your comment:

1) `'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US'` - You must use full locale. Because English locale may be `en_US`, `en_UK` and e.t.c. `The format for the language/locale is ll-CC where ll is a two- or three-letter lowercase code for a language according to ISO-639 and CC is the country code according to ISO-3166.` from `[doc][1]`

2) In key use category. And category set in `Yii::t('category'...)`